# Automatically generate proxy object for GTest mocking

Tags: c++, proxy, googletest, unique-ptr

Given the following application:

```
struct IFooImpl
{
    virtual ~IFooImpl( ) = default;
    virtual void f( ) = 0;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( std::unique_ptr< IFooImpl > impl )
        : m_impl( std::move( impl ) )
    {
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr< IFooImpl > m_impl;
};
```

Need to implement a test (GTest) for Foo with mocks. IFooImpl cannot be simply shared between Foo and test because std::unique_ptr is used. So I would like to implement a proxy which holds shared implementation inside:

```
class FooProxy : public IFooImpl
{
public:
    FooProxy( std::shared_ptr< IFooImpl > impl )
        : m_impl( impl )
    {
    }

    void
    f( ) override
    {
        m_impl->f( );
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr< IFooImpl > m_impl;
};

...

auto mock = std::make_shared<FooMock>();
Foo foo(std::make_unique<FooProxy>(mock));
```

I would like to avoid boilerplate code. Is it possible to generate such FooProxy automatically or at least minimize the number of copy-and-paste? Are there any helpers in GTest?

Comment: "IFooImpl cannot be simply shared between Foo and test because std::unique_ptr is used" Why? You can either extract raw pointer from `unique_ptr` before passing it to unit under test or you can set all `EXPECT_CALL` before. Changing production code to match tests is generally frowned upon.

Comment: *"`IFooImpl` cannot be simply shared between `Foo` and test because `std::unique_ptr` is used"*. How about `auto mock = std::make_unique<FooImplMock>(); EXPECT_CALL(*mock, f())/*..*/; Foo foo(std::move(mock)); /*..*/`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I try to avoid raw pointers because they are source of potential problems. I realize that it's acceptable to write "bad code" in tests but still wondering if there are good alternative solutions

Comment: @Jarod42 Interesting idea but this will not cover complex cases when need to make more than 1 call.

Comment: You can set-up whole mocking before `foo` usage normally, else you can still keep an (observer) pointer on `mock.get()` to use afterward.

Comment: Raw pointers are exactly the same amount of problems as smart pointers, except you have to worry about ownership as well. Since you do have your ownership managed well by `unique_ptr`, there's no much risk in getting a raw pointer as observer for use in test. Or set up all mock calls before giving up `unique_ptr` ownership, I can't think of any use case where you cannot set up every mock call upfront.